# What causes the session to be recreated or to be gone after a page refresh?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using codeigniter on my project, and I have a login module and I authenticate each module. When the session does not exist then redirect to the login page. So, this works but sometimes it may happen when I login and then refresh the page I get redirected to the login page (meaning the session is gone).

Please do not try to tell me to use another library such as php native etc. I just want to know what the problem causing this is.

```
function _admin_login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->login_rules);

    $data['title'] = "Login";
    $data['form_url'] = $this->uri->uri_string();   
    $data['login_btn'] = form_submit('login','Sign In','class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary"');


        if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){

            $data['user'] = form_input('username','','class="input-block-level input-large" placeholder="Username"');
            $data['passw'] = form_password('password','','class="input-block-level input-large" placeholder="Password"');

            $this->template->set('title','Login');
            $this->template->load('template_login','login_view',$data);

        }else{
            $username = $this->input->post('username',true);
            $row = $this->authentication_model->get_user_info($username);

            $this->session->set_userdata('user',$row['user_id']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('username',$row['username']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('login_state',true);
            $this->authentication_model->update_last_login();


                redirect('product');    
        }

}
```

This is my login script, if the validation passes then the session is set... and in every controller I have checked the session script. Example below:

```
$this->authentication_plugin->check_logged_in();

function check_logged_in()
    {
        if(logged_in() === FALSE){
            set_alert('Login in to view this page!!','error');
            set_bookmark('login_url');
            redirect("login");
        }
    }

function logged_in()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $user = $CI->session->userdata('user');

    if(!$CI->load->library('session')){
            echo "no session is loaded";
            die;
    }

    if(!empty($user)){      
        return true;
    }else{  
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: is there any username duplicates in your datebase? First I would check the `$row = $this->authentication_model->get_user_info($username);`

Comment: `if(logged_in() === FALSE)` should be `if($this->logged_in() === FALSE)`

Comment: the logged_in() is global library function.. does not matter

Comment: jcs - no just one record.. did you guys had meet this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- autoload the session library and remove that from your login script.
  In config/autoload.php look for $autoload['libraries'] 
  add 'session'
- in config/config.php
  scroll down to cookie configs and look for $config['sess_cookie_name'] 
  make sure there is no underscore in the cookie name. you have to change the codeigniter default name to do this.
- test by doing session checks in the constructor. its a quick sanity check to see if the sessions are working or not.

Comment: Great!! thanks you Cartalot. it is work~ your second suggestion is helped me.

Comment: ok~ i found that the problem to causes this is not really change the name, this is because i run 2 application on the same time and the session name is same using ci_session. maybe it have collision

Comment: its a good habit to give the cookie name a unique value when you first set up the application. and dont use underscores in cookie names. AND - try not to rely on cookies. you can pass unique session with tokens. no cookies no cry.